# Email newsletter from php mail function not sending anymore

Tags: php, email

I have a page that I set up in php to send newsletters to emails who sign up on my website. The code worked just fine when I sent it to 30 emails the other day. Everyone received the email newsletter. Two new people signed up and now when I try to send one, it goes through as if it sent without any errors in the code, but no one ever receives the newsletter.

Would it have anything to do with an invalid email address that stops it from working? As if one of the new ones is not valid and it shuts it down? I did nothing to change the code from when it was working to the previous 30 emails. My hosting company allows over 250 emails per day, so that is not the problem at all.

```
$mailto = "members@example.com" ;
$headers = "From: chris@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: chris@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: $emails \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$from='members@example.com';
$subject="TEST";
$body='<html><body>';
$body.= "<table><tr><td>$content etc...</td></td> </body></html>";
if (mail($mailto,$subject,$body,$headers)) { 
code... ; } 
else { 
code... ; }
```

Comment: Without seeing some code anything is really a wild guess.  Though I suggest checking the return value of the mail function if you are not already doing so.

Comment: $mailto = "members@example.com" ;


$headers = "From: chris@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: chris@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: $emails \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$from='members@example.com';
$subject="TEST";
$body='<html><body>';
$body.= "<table><tr><td>$content etc...</td></td>
</body></html>"; </code></pre>

if (mail($mailto,$subject,$body,$headers)) {

  code... ;
  }
 else {
 code... ; }

Comment: @ChrisFilippou please edit your question and add the snippet there instead of in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this line:

```
$headers .= "BCC: $emails \r\n";
```

you put all the recipients into one single header line.

This may fail for at least 3 reasons:

1. as soon as this line is longer that 998 characters, the message violates [rfc2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) and so the mail server may reject it.
2. most SMTP servers have a limit on the number of recipients in a single message, so at some point this limit is going to be reached (30 recipients don't seem that much, though).
3. any serious syntax error in an email address may invalidate the whole line.

Also, it may help to know which SMTP server is used here. If you have access to the mail server logs, obviously you should check that, too.

As a workaround, you may want to loop through your list of subscriber and send one different message to each subscriber in the `To` field and not use `Bcc` at all. This is also better to get through spam filters, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is use some SMTP server, say google, and PHPMailer, or anything similar. THis is probably the best solution for you too, because the usage of mail function in PHP might be a bit dangerous. Many mail servers think that these emails are spam, due to them not being sent by a known service. 
At first, try finding out if the unreceived emails have landed in the spam folder.
If not, and if your time doe not allow a PHPMailer implementation, try sending the emails manually from a PHP snippet code, see what really happens.